# WCF DataContractSerializer and KnownTypes

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

I have the following WCF Service

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyClass))]
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Table GetData();

    }

}
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
     public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Table GetData()
        {
            var table = new Table();
            var record = new Record { };
            record.Add("record1",new MyClass { Name ="test"});

            table.Records.Add(record);

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

The WCF reference a Class library in other assembly :

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(MyClass))]
    public class Table
    {

        public Table()
        {
            Records = new List<Record>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
    }


    [KnownType(typeof(MyClass))]
    [DataContract]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [CollectionDataContract]
    public class Record : IDictionary<string, object>
    {

        private IDictionary<string, object> innerDictionnary = new Dictionary<string, object>();


        public void Add(string key, object value)
        {
            innerDictionnary.Add(key, value);
        }

        // … here the rest of IDictionary<string, object> Implementation
}
```

In another project I referenced the WCF Service and I called the GetDate Method :

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            var x = client.GetData();

        }
```

and I have this error:

> http//schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ClassLibrary1:Value' contains
>   data from a type that maps to the name
>   'http//schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ClassLibrary1:MyClass'. The
>   deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to
>   'MyClass' to the list of known types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known
>   types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.

I tried many solutions found in other posted question, but nothing works

Comment: Why you have put `[KnownType(typeof(MyClass))]` everywhere?

Comment: I tried adding [KnownType (typeof (MyClass))] everywhere to resolve the problem, and it was useless

Comment: Add [KnownType(typeof(IEnumerable<MyClass>))] instead.  There's lots of good information on using the DCS with collections here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850(v=vs.110).aspx